# How import default.css in custom theme file for laravel notification?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, themes

How import default.css in custom thrme file for laravel notification?
Standard css import does not work

```css
@import "default.css";

.logo-img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 18%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Console errors for mailtrap
[image]

Comment: is it throwing an error? Where is your default.css ? Can you check in developer tools in chrome? Can you try to do it as url("default.css") ?

Comment: both css files are in html/theme. url("default.css") not work too. Custom styles without import line are applied. But with import line custom styles not work too.

Comment: does chrome console gives an error? Can you check it?

Comment: @gguney  I added screen with errors from chrome console. I use mailtrap for emails checking. Stylese from .css file shoulde added in html tags like inline style, but it is empty.

Comment: Can you try run it without your chrome extensions. Kaspersky blocking some urls

Comment: I checked it in incognito mode and have not any errors in console but styles not work